# Finding several consecutive sessions with the same users

Tags: perl

I have a log of users' sessions, each session is defined by two users' IDs which are unique. the attached picture is a sample of such a log->

[image: log image]

I need to retrieve those lines where couple of users established several consecutive sessions between each other and that those users didn't communicate with other users between these sessions.  Also there is a condition on max interval between sessions - the period between finish-time of the previous session and the "start-time" of the following shouldn't exceed 75 sec.

By green color I marked the users IDs which had consecutive sessions(no sessions with other users were between), the trickiest thing is that A and B users both can initiate sessions and I need to find them all.
By red color I marked the case when there are two sessions established by the same users, but they appeared to be not consecutive as the user 1632300508 connected with some third party user - 1752301123  before calling back to 1522909598. - such cases shouldn't be selected.
I would be very thankful to you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Handle::CSV;

my $log_file = Tie::Handle::CSV->new('userlog', header => 1);

my %last_contact;

while ( my $log_entry = <$log_file> )
   {
   my $userA = $log_entry->{'userA'};
   my $userB = $log_entry->{'userB'};  
   my $start = $log_entry->{'start-time'};
   my ($h,$m,$s) = split /:/, $start;
      $start      = $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s;
   my $end       = $log_entry->{'start-time'};
   my ($h,$m,$s) = split /:/, $end;
      $end       = $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s        

   if (  ( $last_contact{ $last_contact->{user}->{$userA} } eq $userA )
      && defined $last_contact{ $userA }->{'finish'}
      && ( $last_contact{ $userA }->{'finish'} - $start < 75 ))
      {
      print "Users $userA and $userB have consecutive sessions in less than 75 seconds\n";
      }
   else
      {
      $last_contact{$userA}->{'user'}   = $userB;
      $last_contact{$userA}->{'finish'} = $end;
      $last_contact{$userB}->{'user'}   = $userA;
      $last_contact{$userB}->{'finish'} = $end;
      }
   }
```

So, I would use a hash whose keys are users and whose values are their last contact.  If the last contact of a user is used as a key and points back to the first user then they are their last contact and you take some action (here I just print out that fact).  Otherwise, take the two users and set their last contacts to each other.

Edited to track time and make sure it is under 75 second.